# Azure Data Factory - Date time format issue

Tags: azure-data-factory

Date format I need is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", but i can get like this "yyyy-MM-dd T HH:mm:ss"
How can i remove the T word this in azure data factory activity.

Is there any way to remove T word?

expected output: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADF's built-in function formatDateTime() to format the date:

```
formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Note: `utcnow()` is a built-in function which will return current time in UTC.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response can you explain with example.

Comment: Hi @raj,
You will be using formatdate in which activity?

Comment: copy data activity